# Detecting planes and tap events with ARCore

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm trying to understand [Google's ARCore API](https://developers.google.com/ar/) and pushed their [sample project (`java_arcore_hello_ar`) to GitHub](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/java_arcore_hello_ar).

In this example, when you deploy the app to your Android, any horizontal surfaces/planes are detected. If you tap on a detected plane, "Andy" the Andrid robot will be rendered in the location that you tap. Pretty cool.

I'm trying to find where in the code:

1. Thats a horizontal surface/plane gets detected; and
2. Where the logic lives to resize & re-orient Andy correctly (I assume if the point you tap is further away from the camera, he will be rendered small, etc.)

I *believe* when planes are detected, that the Android framework calls the `onSurfaceCreated` method:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);

    // Create the texture and pass it to ARCore session to be filled during update().
    mBackgroundRenderer.createOnGlThread(/*context=*/this);
    mSession.setCameraTextureName(mBackgroundRenderer.getTextureId());

    // Prepare the other rendering objects.
    try {
        mVirtualObject.createOnGlThread(/*context=*/this, "andy.obj", "andy.png");
        mVirtualObject.setMaterialProperties(0.0f, 3.5f, 1.0f, 6.0f);

        mVirtualObjectShadow.createOnGlThread(/*context=*/this,
            "andy_shadow.obj", "andy_shadow.png");
        mVirtualObjectShadow.setBlendMode(BlendMode.Shadow);
        mVirtualObjectShadow.setMaterialProperties(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read obj file");
    }
    try {
        mPlaneRenderer.createOnGlThread(/*context=*/this, "trigrid.png");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read plane texture");
    }
    mPointCloud.createOnGlThread(/*context=*/this);
}
```

However that code *looks like* it assumes the user has already tapped on the surface. I'm not seeing an `if`-conditional that basically says "*Render Andy **if** the user has tapped on a detected plane/surface.*". Can anyone spot where this might be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tap detection is done by in the [mGestureDetector](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/6fb994e98b497232880005231c93be23a7c5acac/samples/java_arcore_hello_ar/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/helloar/HelloArActivity.java#L99-L110):

```
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        onSingleTap(e);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Which is linked to the [SurfaceView](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/6fb994e98b497232880005231c93be23a7c5acac/samples/java_arcore_hello_ar/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/helloar/HelloArActivity.java#L112-L117)

```
mSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Both things happen in `onCreate()`, so now every time you tap the surface view (the "main" view in the activity),

```
private void onSingleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    // Queue tap if there is space. Tap is lost if queue is full.
    mQueuedSingleTaps.offer(e);
}
```

is called and the tap is stored. This queue is then processed in every frame drawing (which in turn is issued by the system's UI drawing cycle) [here](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/6fb994e98b497232880005231c93be23a7c5acac/samples/java_arcore_hello_ar/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/helloar/HelloArActivity.java#L112-L117)

```
MotionEvent tap = mQueuedSingleTaps.poll();
if (tap != null && frame.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
    for (HitResult hit : frame.hitTest(tap)) {
       ...
```

This adds a new anchor (i.e. a point "locked" in the physical world") at which an Android object is rendered [(cf. this line)](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/6fb994e98b497232880005231c93be23a7c5acac/samples/java_arcore_hello_ar/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/helloar/HelloArActivity.java#L112-L117).

Comment: Thanks @PhilLab (+1) - so are you saying that `GLSurfaceView`'s touch listener is where ARCore can detect touch events for a given surface/plane? If so, how is that code linked to the `onSurfaceCreated` method (which gets called first -> the touch listener's `onTouch` or `onSurfaceCreated`)?

Comment: the touch listener only adds the touch to the processing queue. From which it is then polled in the draw method

Comment: Thanks @PhilLab (+1 again) I'm following *most* of what you're saying, except one thing: where (specifically) is the app/framework detecting that the user tapped on a particular flat plane (as opposed to just tapping on something that isn't plane, and hence, can't result with "Andy" being rendered on it)? Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah I took a second look this morning at your answer and the code and I think we're definitely missing *something* here. First I think we need to clarify exactly what a `GLSurfaceView` is. After reading its Javadocs, I'm unclear as to whether it represents a (detected) flat/horizontal plane, or if it just represents the outer texture of any (plane or otherwise) 3D object. The code will make a wee bit of more sense to me after I can understand that!

Comment: But even then, I still would think that there has to be code *somewhere* that looks at the tap (which I assume is a `MotionEvent` instance) and confirms that the tap actually occurred over/at a location where a flat plane was detected. I'm looking for where that check is occurring...any ideas? Thanks again so much!

Comment: This is `frame.hitTest(tap)`